# Creating a mock IHttpFilter for testing Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-runtime, mocking, tdd

I want to create a "mock" `IHttpFilter` implementation for testing calls with the `Windows.Web.Http HttpClient`. This is my SendRequestAsync method in the implementation

```
 public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<HttpResponseMessage,HttpProgress> 
    SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(_statusCode);
                response.Content = _content;

                //This is the problematic part
                return AsyncInfo.Run<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress>(
                    (token, progress) => Task.Run<HttpResponseMessage>(
                        () => { return response; }));           
            }
```

In my test method I use it like this. This is also the way that the `HttpClient` would be used in an application.

```
//This Throws an InvalidCastException
var result = await client.SendRequestAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("http://www.nomatter.com")));
```

But it throws an InvalidCastException

```
Result Message: Test method UnitTestLibrary1.UnitTest.TestHttp threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at UnitTestLibrary1.UnitTest.<TestHttp>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\****\UniversalPCLUnitTest\UnitTestLibrary1\UnitTest1.cs:line 40
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

I cannot find out why the exception is thrown. Has anybody faced the same problem??

Answer (score -1):

There are two answers to this question.

The first answer is that you should not even attempt to Mock out a System.Net.HttpClient. This class should be instanced ONCE in your app, maybe as a Singleton.

You would typically wrap the use of HttpClient into a contract of some kind, IE

```
public interface ICanGetHttpBodies{
    string AsString(Uri uri);
}
```

And then of course, use that contract, and mock it out whenever you need to:

```
[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(ProgramException))]
public void MyMethod_WhenEmptyBody_ThrowsException()
{
    // Arrange 
    var emptyBody = "";
    var getBodyMock = new Mock<ICanGetHttpBodies>()
        .Setup(m => m.AsString(It.IsAny<Uri>())
        .Returns(emptyBody);

    // Act & Assert
}
```

This way, you have complete control of your code flow, you have hidden the HttpClient in a Contract that gives you meaning (ICanGetHttpBodies) which makes the code easier to read too (free bonus:) )

The second answer is that there is something called "Fakes" in Visual Studio that can give you the ability to stub/mock out static libraries like HttpClient and DateTime:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Hope any of this helps, and that you preferred answer option 1 :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the insight on Fakes. As I read in the link they are only available on VS Enterprise which I don't have.
Also I notice that in your answer you refer to System.Net.HttpClient while my question is about Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient. Creating "mock" IHttpFilter implementations are actually the way microsoft proposed for testing with this HttpClient. So I am looking for an answer with an IHttpFilter implementation

Comment: in mocking System.Net.HttpClient however you may find [this](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp) library by richardszalay interesting

Comment: Sorry, I see now that I replied to the wrong thing there - it does seem strange that you'd want to try mock filters with HttpClient - why not simply use stubs?

Comment: G Dias I will use stubs for the most part of the application. But I will also need more "fine grain" tests concerning the HttpClient.

Comment: Isn't the question about Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient instead of the one in System.Net?